# store image in mysql and retrieve it

Tags: java, mysql, image, jsp, servlets

I am creating a website with jsp&servlet

and I want to ask :

What's the best way to store an image in a database (mysql) and retrieve it

to using it as profile's picture

And how can i do that?

Thanks you all in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two common solutions :

- directly in the database in a byte field
- on the disk, with the path stored in database (I personnaly like to use as name the SHA1 of the file, so I cannot have two times the same file, with the path being a/b/cdef if the SHA1 is abcdef)

Both solutions work very well. The first solution has for advantage to have only one file to backup, to enable rollback, and so on. The second may be more natural as a disk file system is made to store files.

Comment: How can i implement the second solution?

Comment: You have to receive the image (google "upload servlet"), find the SHA1 of the file content (google "MessageDigest SHA1 java"), deduce a local path from this SHA1, store the file on disk, store the local path on your database.

Answer (score 2):

save image in a folder on the server.
save image path in db .
at the time of display get the image path from db and retrieve image.

Answer (score 1):

Store image in database.

```
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class insertImage{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Insert Image Example!");
      String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
      String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";;
      String dbName = "databasename";
      String userName = "root";
      String password = "root";
      Connection con = null;

      try{
       Class.forName(driverName);
       con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
       Statement st = con.createStatement();
       File imgfile = new File("images.jpg");
       FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(imgfile);
       PreparedStatement pre = con.prepareStatement("insert into Tablename values(?)");
       pre.setBinaryStream(3,fin,(int)imgfile.length());
       pre.executeUpdate();
       System.out.println("Inserting Successfully!");
       pre.close();
       con.close(); 
     }
     catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
    }
   }
```

Retrieve image from database using Servlet
http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/retreiveimage.shtml